# What environment variables can be used with a Docker image?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm just learning Docker. If I want to use a particular image from Docker Hub, such as mysql, how do I know what environment variables can be used with that Docker image? Any way to get a list of the available variables?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at any Dockerfile, search for lines that begin with `ENV`:

```
cat Dockerfile | grep ENV
```

If only an image is available, you can always do (`--format=...` is optional):

```
docker history --format="{{.CreatedBy}}" --no-trunc myimage  | grep ENV
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run it and see. This is what I got when I tried to run

```
docker run -it mysql
error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified 
  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to get the list of env variables:

1. You can checkout Dockerfile and look for `ENV` or `docker run` command and look for `-e` key value.
2. You can also check what actual env variables are populated in running container by following command -

   `docker exec -it <container id> env`

This will give you a list of all populated env vars in that container.